# "Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received" on LR controller

Tags: c, performance, loadrunner

Scenario: We are trying to download 2500 PDFs from our website and we need to find the response time of this scenario when run with other business flows of the application. The custom code I had written for selecting and downloading PDFs dynamically worked fine for the size of 200-300 PDFs both on vugen and even on controller. But, when we ran the  same script with 2500 PDFs loaded to the DB, the script worked fine on vugen, but failed running out of memory on controller. I tried running this script alone on controller for concurrent users (20) and even then it failed giving the same out of memory error.I started getting this error as soon as the concurrent users started running on the server.

I tried following things and my observations:

1. I checked the LG we are using and had no high cpu usage/memory usage at the time I got this memory error.

2. I tried turning off the logging completely and also turned off the "Generate snapshot on error".

3. I increased the network buffer size from default 12KB to a higher value around 2MB as the server was responding with THAT PDF size.

4. Also, increased JavaScript runtime memory value to a higher value but I know it's something to do with the code.

5. I have set `web_set_max_html_param_len("100000");`

Here is my code:

```
int download_size,i,m;
m=atoi(lr_eval_string("{DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices_count}"));
for(i=1;i<=m;i++)   
lr_param_sprintf("r_buf","%sselectedNotice=%s&",lr_eval_string("{r_buf}"),lr_paramarr_idx("DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices",i));
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{r_buf}"), "dpAllRecords");
```

I am not able to find what the issue with my code as it is running fine in vugen.

One thing is: it creates huge mdrv.log file to accommodate all the 2500 members in the format shown above

`"%sselectedNotice=%s&"`.

I need help on this.

Okay, since that did not work and I could not find the root cause, I tried modifying the code with string buffer to hold the value instead of the parameter. This time my code did not work properly and I could not get the proper formatted value resulting in my web_custom_request failing

so, here is the code with sprintf

```
char *r_buf=(char *) malloc(55000);
int download_size,i,m;
m=atoi(lr_eval_string("{DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices_count}"));
for(i=1;i<=m;i++)   
sprintf(r_buf,"%sselectedNotice=%s&",r_buf,lr_paramarr_idx    ("DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices",i));
lr_save_string(r_buf, "dpAllRecords");
```

I also tried using this:

```
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{r_buf}"), "dpAllRecords");
```

though it is for embedded parameters but in vain

Comment: Where is the error actually occurring is it while the string is building? I would try allocating way more than 55000 bytes. I would also put in lr_message() logging to see how far in the 2500 PDFs it gets to. If it's near the end then you know it's your string length that's the problem. It could be that one of the "DownloadableRecords" values is randomly very long. Try building a bunch of smaller strings say groups of 500 and joining those together to see what happens.

Comment: From the LR v12.02 manual on lr_eval_string(): _Note: lr_eval_string allocates memory internally. The memory is automatically freed at the end of each iteration. You can use lr_eval_string_ext and manually free the memory in each iteration with lr_eval_string_ext_free. Do not, however, use a free statement in your custom code, as this may result in memory corruption._ -- So allocating too many of them might cause a out of memory error

Comment: To minimize and make your code faster I suggest changing:
`m=atoi(lr_eval_string("{DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices_count}"));` 
to `m = lr_paramarr_len("DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices");`

Comment: @MichaelGalos  Sorry that I have asked for solution to two problems at a time. The custom code with  `lr_param_sprintf` is working fine in vugen (for 2500 PDFs) but memory violation's occuring on controller for concurrent users. Where as the custom code with `sprintf` does not work in vugen even when I try to select as low as 20 PDFs. Is it better that I edit it and put the question with `sprintf` as a new one?

Comment: Are you running virtual users on your controller?  If so, start by addressing that and running NO virtual users on your controller as a load generator.   You should have at least three load generators (2 for primary load and one for a control group)

Comment: @James: We are not using controller as LG, but we are using only one LG. But, the problem is I run **only that particular script** on controller with 20 concurrent users and I still get out of memory errors. If I use the hardcoded values (which doesn't change if the date range is fixed), the script runs fine on controller even with all other scripts running. Also,as said before, I do not see any substantial performance issues with the LG we are using. While our load test is running, at the peak,it just uses 20% of CPU and memory usage of around 5GB (RAM is 64GB)

Comment: Getting back to your log...you should only be logging errors during the test or the file system will become a bottleneck to the test and you may run out of disk space.  If you need a way to validate then look for the PDF heeader existence, the footer existence and the size (just below the final footer).  Compare that to the size of the last download.  Then you can say you have a valid PDF without logging

Comment: Yea, when I run from vugen the download size  was eqaul to the one with manual download.On the controller, when I checed the mdrv. log file for the failed test with memory errors, I could see that the `r_buf` parameter we are using is not able to hold the concatenated formatted output as the number of PDFs selected increased. So, the memory error occured at the concatenation of say, 1000th PDF select and it was random for different vusers though.

Comment: The below sample is from the actual log file which says that at the select of 1005th PDF, it could not allocate anymore memory to r_buf (and for the next test I turned off the logging): `File_ACK.c(162): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices_1005" =  "93386" [MsgId: MMSG-13992]
File_ACK.c(162): Error: Failed to allocate memory of size: 84420 for sending message to log file [MsgId: MERR-13873]
End auto log messages stack. [MsgId: MMSG-10544]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below. If frees the allocated memory, something you do not do in your examples.

I changed:

- The way r_buf is allocated
- how r_buf is populated (doing a sprintf() into the buffer and from the buffer might not work as expected)
- uses lr_paramarr_len()
- FREES THE ALLOCATED BUFFER!
- Check that the allocated buffer is big enough in the loop

**Action() Code:**

```
char *r_buf;
char buf[2048];
int download_size,i,m;

// Allocate memory
if ( (r_buf= (char *)calloc(65535 * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
{
    lr_error_message ("Insufficient memory available");
    return -1;
}
memset( buf, 0, sizeof(buf) );

m = lr_paramarr_len("DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices");

for(i=1; i<=m; i++) {
  sprintf( buf, "selectedNotice=%s&", lr_paramarr_idx("DownloadableRecords_FundingNotices",i) );

  // Check buffer is big enough to hold the new data
  if ( strlen(r_buf)+strlen(buf) > 65535 ) {
    lr_error_message("Buffer exceeded");
    lr_abort();
  }

  // Concatenate to final buffer
  strcat( r_buf, buf ); // Bugfix: This was "strcat( r_buf, "%s", buf );"
}

// Save buffer to variable
lr_save_string(r_buf, "dpAllRecords");

// Free memory
free( r_buf );
```

Comment: @sandell: I has used `free(r_buf)` before too, but forgot to mention that. Anyway, I still tried with the above code using strcat but I still do not get the expected formatted output. It gives the same result as before. I used `lr_output_message(buf)` soon after `sprintf` and I could see that proper formatted string is getting saved. For eg: `"selectedNotice=83141&"`, but sometimes I also strated getting **Buffer exceeded** strangely. I used `lr_output_message(r_buf)` at the end of the for loop to see what's getting stored and i see this **var dtCh= "/"; var minYear=1900; var maxYear=2100;**

Comment: Maybe we need to see more of the actual script you have to understand the amount of data you push into `r_buf`. I'm not sure I completely understand all the aspects of the problem you have.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a bugfix. Stupid me made `strcat()` typo, and changed `malloc()` to `calloc()` to zero the r_buf from the start.

Comment: After the changes I now get as output (with 5 play data):  
`selectedNotice=1001&selectedNotice=1002&selectedNotice=1003&selectedNotice=1004&selectedNotice=1005&`

Comment: Actually I had used the strcat(*dest, *src) properly :). But, the problem was with malloc. Since malloc does not set r_buf to zero, you need memset to initiallize r_buf **OR** use calloc which sets zero bits to r_buf. And the syntax for calloc is a bit different here :) `r_buf= (char *)calloc(65535, sizeof(char)`

Comment: And why would the r_buf, which is handled the way we handled it before did not have proper concatenated formatted string? When we use malloc (forgetting to use memset on r_buf), would it have initialized the r_buf to some random array of chars causing it to concatenate badly and giving the bad string as I mentioned above? Also, from performance point of view is it good to use malloc and memset call or calloc? I agree that calloc takes a bit of overhead in setting the zero bits to the memory but again it saves the call to memset right? I am not sure which works faster?

Comment: I guess using `malloc()` and not zero:ing the buffer is a sure way to complicate things. As for speed/performance, my gutt feeling is `calloc()` is faster. I think using `calloc()` is better as it does 2 things at the same time.

Comment: Yea, it works now :) just for the small syntax change with `calloc()`as said above. But, I haven't tested yet for concurrent users and for very large PDFs. I will try that and lets see